# Howto insert geometry in h2 using sql

Tags: sql, geospatial, h2, spatial

Since a couple of versions, h2 does have support for spatial geometries.

It's not a problem to select and insert geometries in java. But how can insert them in pure sql? [Documentation](http://www.h2database.com/html/datatypes.html#geometry_type) shows it uses WKT. But when I try to insert in WKT I got an error.

That's an example insert:

```
insert into feature (id, name, description, geom) values
(1, 'example name', 'example description', 'SRID=4326;POINT(7 52)');
```

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I see, the suffix `SRID=4326` is not [WKT (Well-Known Text)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text), but EWKT.

The H2 database currently does not support [EWKT (Extended Well-Known Text)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text#Variations). You would have to use `'POINT(7 52)'`. A complete example:

```
create table feature(id int, name varchar(255), 
description varchar(255), geom geometry);
insert into feature (id, name, description, geom) values
(1, 'example name', 'example description', 'POINT(7 52)');
```

Answer (score 3):

Spatial functions in H2 database is available in the [H2GIS](http://www.h2gis.org) library. This library is a spatial extension of H2 database. It provides all OGC's simple feature for SQL standards. Using this library you can also [change the coordinate reference system](http://www.h2gis.org/docs/dev/ST_Transform/) of your data.

If you don't want to use H2GIS you can define SRID by using alias method of H2:

```
create alias ST_GeomFromText AS $$
com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry fromText(String wkt, int srid) throws SQLException {
    if(wkt == null) {
        return null;
    }
    try {
        com.vividsolutions.jts.io.WKTReader wktReaderSRID = new com.vividsolutions.jts.io.WKTReader(new com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.GeometryFactory(new com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.PrecisionModel(),srid));
        com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry geometry = wktReaderSRID.read(wkt);
        return geometry;
    } catch (com.vividsolutions.jts.io.ParseException ex) {
        throw new SQLException(ex);
    }
}$$
```

Then call it:

```
insert into feature (id, name, description, geom) values
(1, 'example name', 'example description', ST_GeomFromText('POINT(7 52)', 4326));
```

You have to place the jts jar file in the h2 classpath in order to use Geometry type.